# Mistake while registering to make an appointment

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I am a uk overseas student I made some mistake while filling form online, and it has been registered with my passport number. What should I do in this case? Do I need to fill it by hand form when I have an appointment? Any suggestion please? I made an appointment on this website

https://www.tlscontact.com/

Comment: What kind of mistake did you make?

Comment: my visa type and my dates of arrival in Shengen country

Comment: I assume you will still get a chance to correct the mistake. If not, it does not look too good but should not necessarily doom the application. The consulate will probably ignore your wishes but can still decide to issue a visa based on the documents you submitted (i.e. for one week instead of 90 days). As a UK resident, you might even be lucky and get a multiple-entry visa anyway as it seems they are somewhat more generous in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry a bit. Message them to say that you will need to do some more changes and they will unfreeze the application so you can make further changes. Just repeat it if you make any mistakes.

If by any god known reason, they cannot unfreeze the application, don't worry a bit. Go to the TLS contact centre and when you enter ask them that you need to do some changes. They will provide you with a new printed form, which you can fill it there. They may crib a bit, but don't worry. People are quite lenient at the centre. I have seen many Chinese students fill up their form again at the contact centre.

Else take a printout of the application form and fill it by hand, before going to the processing centre.

A caveat though, I am talking about London. I am not sure about other places, but I wouldn't assume the processing centres would be filled with idiots who wouldn't allow you to fill in a new form.